# How do you deal with a bad user

Tags: discussion, etiquette

I'd like everyone to familiarize yourselves with [werih](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/8782/werih).

I've taken a look over his contributions and [found them lacking.](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/12982/do-i-need-two-licenses-to-play-starcraft-2-multiplayer-over-a-lan/20528#20528)

I took the liberty of flagging some of his worse comments, but I'm not 100% on how to proceed. His posts sound highly opinionated, so there's the concrete risk that attempts to educate him might be met with stubborn argument.

Where do we go from here?

- Invite to chat?
- Engage in comments?
- Disciplinary action?
- Silently delete his poor answers?

Comment: Please wait a second til I wake up and go through the flag list.

Comment: @tzenes I don't think you should have called out this particular user by name. If he's a troll, it serves no purpose, and is in fact counterproductive; if he isn't, it's pretty unfair and unlikely to induce him to mend his ways (which I agree with you are troublesome).

Comment: This doesn't look like a "bad" user at all.  It looks to me like a passionate user who has some answers that are likely incorrect.  They aren't personal attacks, they aren't spam.  The answers have been downvoted where appropriate.  I'd say nothing more to see here, and personally think we should delete this question so they aren't being "called out" unfairly.

Comment: @Billare I'm going to say the same thing I said to badp: `@badp I came here because I didn't want to start a flame war with the user in comments; I was trying to find a better way. The issue with his posts is that they are obvious flamebait (take the one you deleted for example, or this one ). I think he shows blatant fanboi-ism which makes it almost impossible to separate information from his personal opinions. These aren't bad in the "incorrect" sense, they're bad in the "off topic" sense`

Comment: @bwarner ping on the above

Comment: He's only been a member for 4 days.  He's obviously used to a different culture, but that seems forgivable given how most gaming forums are.  There's a good chance that the more time he spends here, the better he will fit in with our culture.

Comment: @Bwarner maybe this is a Starcraft specific thing, but in any Starcraft community I've encountered his remarks would be considered *extremely* inflammatory.

Comment: I was under the impression that Gaming SE users were encouraged to grow and mature **over time**. I'm not going to pretend I've always been a perfect user, but I did get the hang of things eventually.

Answer (score 6):

Even if you're under the impression that he's going to resist ["education"](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p3h8ZnXLsRg) on how it's expected for users to behave on this site, I feel like you should still leave a comment explaining what bothers you about his contributions. I've been in many situations on the internet where someone who I thought was going to be hostile when approached in a civil manner turned out to be understanding and kind.

He's certainly *passionate* about gaming, or he wouldn't have written that rant about greed inherent in game design these days, and I feel like this, along with a slight misunderstanding as to what sort of tone is expected in an answer(don't post rants, post answers), is responsible for the tone of his answers. So if he's willing to understand that his tone isn't doing him any favors and improve the quality of his answers, I feel like he could be a good user.

As for what to do with the answers, here are my views:

1. If his answer isn't answering the question, as is the case [here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/12982/do-i-need-two-licenses-to-play-starcraft-2-multiplayer-over-a-lan/20528#20528)(or was), **flag it as not an answer**.
2. If he's trying to answer the question but his information is wrong, **downvote and leave a comment explaining his mistakes**.
3. If his tone is what's bothering you, either **downvote or edit**, and then **leave a comment asking him to be more polite**.

Answer (score 5):

Poor content does not warrant moderation. If his answers are poor, downvote.

I see nothing egregiously wrong with what he wrote — and by "wrong" I do not mean "incorrect", I mean "offensive", "spam" or "flamebait". Some of the posts are flagged are indeed similar to others on the same page.

Also, I don't think outing the "bad user" on meta like this is a good starting point. We have a list of users that got flagged the most; "bad users" will automagically float there as you flag. Feel free to point us towards particular cases in "private," perhaps by making ad-hoc rooms on chat (using the "invite to room" feature).

Comment: @badp I came here because I didn't want to start a flame war with the user in comments; Iwas trying to find a better way.  The issue with his posts is that they are obvious flamebait (take the one you deleted for example, or [this one](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/5235/do-some-races-have-major-advantages-over-others-in-starcraft-2/20532#20532) ). I think he shows blatant fanboi-ism which makes it almost impossible to separate information from his personal opinions.  These aren't bad in the "incorrect" sense, they're bad in the "off topic" sense.

Comment: @tzenes I don't see the flamebait, or the bias, in the one you link above. Perhaps the issue is I don't have the game. What I do see is, his answers aren't always targeted, so I'll upvote Mana's comment and downvote his post.